# Any uses of allowing literal NULL with operators?

Tags: sql, null, grammar

Some databases support using literal `NULL` as an operand while others do not. As an example:

```
SELECT 1 + NULL
```

Snowflake: `null` 
BigQuery: *error* 
MySQL: `null` 
Postgres: `null` 
SQLServer: `null`

I'm trying to determine how I should handle this in an application, and was wondering if there are ever any (valid) use cases for when it might be useful to have a literal `null` in an expression? This could also include testing.

Comment: I avoid NULL wherever possible. 1 + NULL === 1 + Unknown; If you perform any operation with an unknown, the result is also (in most cases) unknown.

Comment: It depends on how you want the logic to perform in your application.

Comment: @alexherm could you give an example of what you mean please?

Comment: You may want to use null value condition and replace NULL with 0 or some other value while calculating or comparing to another field, or you may want a NULL value to trigger an error.  Depends on use case.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the expression `1 + NULL` by itself is fairly meaningless, as we would expect it to always evaluate to `NULL` (except, apparently, on BigQuery, where it errors out).  However, `1 + NULL` could arise as the result of some other calculation.  Consider the following data and query:

```
id | val
1  | NULL
2  | 5
2  | 10
3  | NULL
3  | 7
```

and the query:

```sql
SELECT id, 1 + SUM(val) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Here for `id = 1` the aggregate total would evaluate to `1 + NULL`, which would be `NULL` on most databases.  One way around this would be to use `COALESCE()`:

```sql
SELECT id, 1 + COALESCE(SUM(val), 0) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Now for `id` groups having only `NULL` values, we would replace that `NULL` sum by zero.